# How to calculate daily average by quarters

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an `Order` table in our database which has columns including `order_nbr`, `create_ts`, etc.

It is straight forward to calculate the daily average of order count using the following SQL

```
select avg(cnt)
from 
(  
  select date(create_ts) dt, count(distinct order_nbr)
  from order
  group by date(create_ts)
)
```

What if I want to plot the daily average vs quarters? How do I estimate the average within a certain period of time? For presentation purpose, it would be a bar chart with daily average as the y axis and quarters (2017Q3, 2017Q4, 2018Q1, 2018Q2) as the x axis.

All I can think of is this is gonna be `avg` of the `avg` over a running window which is 90 days long. Another thought is maybe create a `Date` Dimension table. So every date will have a corresponding quarter name. I am not clear how to write a SQL query for this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To plot Daily average v/s Quarter, you basically need to calculate average of daily averages in a quarter, and group them based on the quarter.

To get quarter corresponding to a date, you can use the [Quarter()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_quarter) function.

Try the following query:

```
SELECT 
  YEAR(inner_nest.dt) AS yr, 
  QUARTER(inner_nest.dt) AS qtr, 
  AVG(inner_nest.daily_avg) AS daily_avg_qtrwise 
FROM 
(
 SELECT 
   DATE(create_ts) AS dt, 
   COUNT(DISTINCT order_nbr) AS daily_avg 
 FROM order 
 GROUP BY DATE(create_ts) 
) 
GROUP BY 
  YEAR(inner_nest.dt), 
  QUARTER(inner_nest.dt)
```

**Note** that [Quarter()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_quarter) function only returns the quarter number for a particular year. So, you will need to use the year number (yr) alongside the quarter number (qtr), to determine the specific quarter.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add one section to the query to filter the results by a range of dates.
Apply the WHERE statement to pick the fields and results to filter, then use the AND statement to apply additional filters.

For example:

```
select avg(cnt)
from
(
  select date(create_ts) dt, count(distinct order_nbr)
  from order
  where date(create_ts) >= date(START_DATE) and date(create_ts) <= date(END_DATE)
  group by date(create_ts)
)
```

This means that you'll need an individual query for each quarter.

Comment: It is still not clear to me how to query for each quarter and piece them together as a single query.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the `YEAR()` and `QUARTER()` functions and group by them?

```
SELECT
  YEAR(   DATE(create_ts))   AS YearID,
  QUARTER(DATE(create_ts))   AS QuarterID,
  COUNT(DISTINCT order_nbr)
FROM
  order
GROUP BY
  YEAR(   DATE(create_ts)),
  QUARTER(DATE(create_ts))
```

Comment: I believe OP needs daily average Vs quarter. So I am interpreting it as average of daily averages in a quarter